# How to force browser to download images

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am using below code in Javascript controller of Lighting Component to download attachments on Case. It's working for pdf and zip files, but images
are being opened in a new tab. Is there any way to force browser to download images rather than opening them through Javascript?

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'some url';
a.target='_blank';
a.click();
```

Comment: Sounds like a potential security vulnerability in the browser which would be undesirable.

Comment: What can be done about it? We have tried from two different computers, same result. When I run it from sandbox, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download) attribute to your anchor element:

```
a.download = 'desired-filename.ext';
```

Where `desired-filename.ext` is the name of the file, such as `cute-fox.png` or `kitchen.jpg`.

Comment: it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor tag with download attribute:

```
<a href="urlToTheFile" download>Download Me!</a>
```

But I believe you should stick to the same origin policy. If you are trying to download the source from another site it won't download, only open it in the same window. You can add **target="_blank"** attribute to open it in a new window.